# Grails 3.x.x ignores plugin-based scaffolding templates

Tags: templates, grails, plugins, grails-plugin, scaffolding

We have created a theme plugin for Grails since we have a requirement for all our applications to have a common look and feel. The theme has all kinds of TagLibs and also has custom scaffolding templates under src/main/templates/scaffolding.

We then install this plugin into our applications by adding a "compile" dependency in our build.gradle file.

This works in most cases but we are getting inconsistent behavior. Sometimes, the plugin's scaffolding templates are ignored with we do grails generate-all. Interestingly enough, if we do grails install-templates, it is always the plugin's scaffolding templates that are copied into the application. Once we have done this, sometimes generate-all uses the plugin scaffolding templates (now copied into the application), sometimes not.

We tried various versions of grails so see if there are some difference. So far, we found that:

- 3.0.10 seems to require an install-template before generate-all can use the templates
- 3.0.12 seems to use the plugin's scaffolding templates (without needing to run grails install-templates)
- 3.1.1 seems to ignore the plugin's scaffolding templates all the time (with or without install-templates)

We tried all kinds of run-app, clean before/after running generate-all under 3.1.1 and scaffolding templates are ignored.

What we want is for Grails to always use the plugin's scaffolding templates WITHOUT having to do a grails install-templates in the application that uses the plugin (this way, if we run into a situation where the application may have an older copy of the plugin's templates).

What is the magic trick to get a consistent behavior here?

Should we bundle our own generate command in our plugin (if so, any pointers as to how to do this)?

Could Grails version differences between the plugin the application explain the inconsistent behavior (plugin is currently developed in Grails 3.0.11)?

Comment: Looks like the issue may be (at least somewhat) related to this: [https://github.com/grails3-plugins/scaffolding/issues/16](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/scaffolding/issues/16)